# How to initialize a StringBuilder to null

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

Hi all I am facing a problem with `StringBuilder`. While automating, I will assign the value of `testfailed` to a `StringBuilder` as

```
private StringBuilder testFailed = new StringBuilder();

public void Test1()
{
    testFailed = SomeTest();
}

public void Test2()
{
    testFailed = null;

    //testFailed = testFailed.Clear();
    //testFailed = new StringBuilder();

    testFailed = someTest1();
}
```

When ever first test fails, the testFailed `StringBuilder` will append the next test result or if test passes then `testFailed` string will display the testFailed b result value. As I used commented methods and tried it didn't work for that. Let me know any other ways. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what the question is here, or what you are trying to do. Can you please clarify?

Comment: (moderator deletes comments around the subject of accept-rate; too much distraction en-masse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve from this. But I am guessing you want to aggregate the errors from various tests that you are running. If thats the case you dont need to reassign the `StringBuilder` class just use a single instance and use `Appends` on it and your test will return string as a result.

Eg.

```
private StringBuilder testFailed;

public void Test1()
{
    testFailed = new StringBuilder();
    testFailed.AppendLine(SomeTest());
}

public void Test2()
{ 
    testFailed = new StringBuilder();
    testFailed.AppendLine(someTest1());
}
```

I dont know why you are taking this approach, but to each his own. I would also suggest you take a look at NUnit.

Comment: I am very sorry , i was not aware of the accepting Answers . is this same as Is this Link answer usefull to you? or other some way to accept answer please let me know.

Comment: There should be a tick mark to the left of this answer. just click on that

Comment: @Marc Gravell  I  Mean for the second test   stringBuilder should become null and it should have the result of second Test only. it should not append the result of second test with first test.

Comment: updated the answer. Please take  a look at the same.

Comment: : Ok Sure. Thank you ,But still it appending the Previous Test Result to the StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use null as a value - it's a bad idea.  I'd use a list of strings for what you are doing.